# Flutter Route animation animate both new and old route to slide

Tags: flutter, dart

I am able to animate a new route so it appears by sliding from right to left, and goes on top of my current page.

However, I would like to animate both pages (the new and old one). The goal would be that they both slide from right to left, and not just the new one to go on top.

This is my code for only the right one to slide:

```
class SlideRightRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;
  SlideRightRoute({this.page})
      : super(
            pageBuilder: (
              BuildContext context,
              Animation<double> animation,
              Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            ) =>
                page,
            transitionsBuilder: (
              BuildContext context,
              Animation<double> animation,
              Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
              Widget child,
            ) {
              var begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
              var end = Offset.zero;
              var curve = Curves.ease;
              var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

              return SlideTransition(
                position: animation.drive(tween),
                child: child,
              );
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably wanting to use a [TabController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html) with a [TabBarView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBarView-class.html) in a Stateful widget with [SingleTickerProviderStateMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

TabController tabController;

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int activeTab = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          activeTab = tabController.index;
        });
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebAppTest'),
      ),
      body: Expanded(
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          children: <Widget>[
            FirstScreen(), //Index 0
            SecondScreen(), //Index 1
            ThirdScreen(), //Index 2
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        tabController.animateTo(2);
      },
      child: Text('To Screen 3!'),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        tabController.animateTo(0);
      },
      child: Text('To Screen 1!'),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        tabController.animateTo(1);
      },
      child: Text('To Screen 2!'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I didn't know that you can use a `TabBarView` without a Tab bar. Can you explain why you used the `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` ?

Comment: The `TabController` requires a TickerProvider under vsync  - this is for the animation  between tabs. `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` mixes in the required class  to  access the TickerProvider